# Getting Wordpress 404 when accessing /craft/admin

Tags: redirect, htaccess

My current site is with Wordpress in the folder `/blog`. My new Craft install is in a sibling folder `/craft`. When i try to load `brianfeeney.us/craft/admin`, i get the wordpress 404. Must be an `.htaccess` issue, right? Can't figure out or find the solution anywhere.

Comment: You would typically access the craft admin control panel using `brianfeeney.us/admin`. Have you configured your index.php with the proper craft path? `$craftPath = '../craft';`? Might want to reread [installation docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing). And yes, could also be an htaccess issue.

Comment: Do you really mean a sibling folder?  From the URL you're trying to load it looks like a sub-folder.

Comment: the folders are within the same root folder, so I think you'd call them siblings. (?) They aren't nested.

Comment: The craft install will eventually replace my current site (WP), but for now, I'm just trying to get it up and running before I do the redirect. The paths are correct (except I'm also getting the /index.php/ problem that this ('omitScriptNameInUrls' => true) is supposed to solve, but isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wordpress’ .htaccess file](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) and [Craft’s .htaccess file](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/remove-index.php) both use the same strategy: *If the request is not pointing to a valid file or folder, rather than have Apache respond with a 404, re-route the request to index.php.*

It sounds to me like you’ve got a .htaccess fie at your web root which is handling Wordpress’ index.php redirect, and that is taking precedence over Craft’s for whatever reason.

Since your Wordpress install lives within /blog/, you should move that Wordpress .htaccess file to /blog/.htaccess, so it’s only affecting blog/* requests. (You’ll also need to tweak it a bit; post the file’s contents if you need help with that.) Or another option is you could add this condition it, before the RewriteRule line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
```

Likewise, Craft’s .htaccess file should live at /craft/.htaccess (no modification will be necessary as the one Craft ships with already accounts for the possibility that it’s within a subfolder), or a similar `RewriteCond` line could be added to it if you really want to keep all your redirects in one place at /.htaccess.